# How to detect disconnection of usb0 device (USB gadget aka g_ether)?

Tags: linux, networking, embedded, embedded-linux

Two Linux machines (embedded board and PC) are connected to each other via USB cable, and communication is established via USB gadget/Ethernet. Both sides have IP address, ping works, etc.

I need to find a way to detect USB cable disconnect on the board side, ideally with a single Bash command.

`ifconfig usb0` still shows IP address and that device is "UP" and "RUNNING" even after unplugging the cable.

Comment: How is your board handles ID pin? It looks like either a hardware (PCB level) issue, or software issue. For example, my Intel Edison board reacts as expected on cable unplug.

Comment: Thanks for the hint -- HW/SW looks like a mess: on the board side ID is pulled down (supposed to be pulled up, right?), but driver (atmel_usba_udc.c) doesn't handle ID pin at all anyway.
/sys/class/udc/300000.gadget/state sometimes switched from "configured" to "default" on unplug, but not always.

Comment: Depends on the usage.ID pin either grounded or floating for the Host / Gadget detection. Otherwise, if I'm not mistaken, when it has a specific resistance (to the ground and to the VBUS) -- charger detection. You may find all these in the corresponding USB specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my particular case it turned out to be HW+SW issue: driver (atmel_usba_udc) is using USB power (VBUS) to detect connection, since it's acting as a slave and power is provided by host. However in PCB power is provided unconditionally by the board itself for all USB ports at once.

Normally any standard method should work: ifconfig or sysfs.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to check the file:

```
/sys/class/net/usb0/operstate
```

If the file content is "up" then the link exists. If the content is "down", then there is no link.

Comment: Unfortunately it's "up" even if the cable is unplugged. Looks like it's a known kernel issue, and I've also tried udev and ifplugd to no avail. Will probably have to do periodic ping.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue on PiZero as gadget (`g_cdc` driver).
Unfortunately `/sys/class/net/usb0/carrier` does not seem available either.

Testing [`current_speed`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/stable/sysfs-class-udc) seems quite successful to detect connect/disconnect status after driver is loaded (allow some time for it to settle).
If cable is connected `current_speed` may be `high-speed` or `full-speed`.
When cable is not connected it is `UNKNOWN`.
Hence the following will report which gadget network usb port is connected:

```
find /sys/class/udc/*/current_speed -exec grep -vl "UNKNOWN" {} \; | \ 
    sed 's|current_speed|device/gadget\.*/net/*|' | \
    while read -r line; do find $line -maxdepth 0 -exec \
        sh -c 'echo ${0##*/} is connected' {} \; ; done
```